# How do I remove suggested URL from omnibox?

Tags: google-chrome

I go to certain websites frequently. One day, when I typed "face" into my Chrome omnibox and hit enter (intending to go to Facebook), I must have done something differently, because it tried to go to "face" as an address (it didn't even search), and my DNS server told me it couldn't find "face." Ever after, "face" has been the first suggested URL by Chrome if I ever typed "f," "fa," "fac," or "face." This is very annoying.

How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On Linux:**
Highlight the entry with your mouse or arrow keys and press `shift` + `alt` + `delete`.

**On Mac OS X:**
Highlight the entry with your mouse or arrow keys and press `shift` + `fn` + `delete`.

**On Windows:**
I think you highlight the entry and press `shift` + `delete`. I have not tested this.